# Loading a local html file on jar into web engine

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem in loading an HTML file to my application onto my web engine.

Currently, if I run my application throw IntelliJ IDE. The HTML page is being loaded correctly! But when I make the project and I run the application to my terminal. The HTML file isn't being loaded at all.

My code for loading HTML page to my web engine.

```
WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
we.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String htmlFile = getClass().getResource("/html/index.html").toExternalForm();
System.out.println(">>>"+htmlFile);
we.load(htmlFile);
```

Why do I have my println ? To check the path of my HTML page.
It seems that when I run it on my project IntelliJ. The application runs correctly. As shown under:

```
>>>file:/Developer/Liss-SDE/out/production/liss/html/index.html
```

But when I do it on my terminal. It prints me something which I don't understand.

```
>>>jar:file:/Users/damien/Desktop/liss%7cSDE/liss.jar!/html/index.html
```

Why does it put a **jar:** at the beginning? Also why is he putting a **!** to my program *.jar* ? And if we compare to the other print, it is totally different!

I extracted the .jar file to check if the directory and the HTML file was missing, but everything is ok.
So what is the problem that I am having?

Comment: `jar:file:/Users/damien/Desktop/liss%7cSDE/liss.jar!/html/index.html` is the [`JarURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) syntax for describing a location in a jar.

Comment: Oh it's been too long since I did this stuff.. :) I think you shouldn't need to do all the stuff with the Jar and FileSystem APIs that I mention below. `getResource()` is already working for you: to get the contents of the file, use `getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: So I use this method (resulting to an **InputStream** and I must convert it to String for loading into the web engine ?

Comment: Also, notice that, **getResource()** is working when I run the application throw my IDE (IntelliJ in this case). Not when I am running the jar throw my terminal.

Comment: Don't know. I suggest taking the command line version as "correct", and treat what the IDE does with suspicion. Check your class path, your manifest, etc. If some magic in your IDE is masking a bug in your code or configuration, then unfortunately there's a bug in your code or configuraiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed in solving this...

And I think this is a weird thing sincerely...

If I collapse all my code into the loading of the web engine everything works correctly...

**sigh**

I hope that future adventurers will not have this issue as I got...

Simply do that:

```
we.load(this.getClass().getResource("/html/index.html").toExternalForm());
```

I don't know if it is a bug or not... Because I didn't changed anything to my project unless putting this line of code...

Thank you to Paul Hicks for trying to help me :)

**BUT** I found a bug ! XD

So if I click with my mouse to my .jar, the application runs correctly! But if I run the .jar throw my terminal by writing `java -jar liss.jar`, then it appears that the application doesn't work! xD
I don't know why sincerely...

Answer (score 4):

The name of the file, with the `jar:` and the `!`, is the URL to the file in the JAR, as defined in [JarURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html).  Using `getResource()` on this is showing the file correctly. Use `getResourceAsStream()` to access the file contents, which should be enough in your case.

You can also get direct access to the contents of your jar using the java jar API. There is a good introduction with a couple of examples at this [java2s tutorial page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_io/0850__Java_io_Jar_API.htm). For jars in your class path (which seems to be the case this time) the jar API is used automatically for you within the `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` methods of `Class`.

From Java 7 onwards, the FileSystem api has been available and hides some of the more awkward details. This [Oracle technote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) gives a concise introduction to the API and how to use it.

Snippet from that page, tweaked to your case:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class WhatsInMyJarFile {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        // locate file system by using the syntax 
        // defined in java.net.JarURLConnection
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/Users/damien/Desktop/liss%7cSDE/liss.jar");

       try (FileSystem jarfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri)) {
            Path pathInJarfile = jarfs.getPath("/html/index.html");
            doStuff(Files.newInputStream( pathInJarfile ));
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i extracted my jar, the html directory was there ! I did IDEA built-in as a build procedure.

Comment: Yes my html file was there, inside of my jar (at least it appears when i extract it) and  I am using IDEA for building my jar.

Comment: I am confused with this code. Firstly because it has an absolute path and secondly, should I do that ?

Comment: It's just example code to show what methods are available